# using variable in awk

Tags: awk

Hello I would like to count number of words with specific lengths. I'm using this command.

```
awk 'length == 2' mydict.txt | wc -l
```

this code gives what I want but if try to put variable instead of number 2 it doesnt work. The code is like this

```
awk 'length == $var' mydict.txt | wc -l
```

and terminal prints 0. What can I do?

Comment: not that the commnad you came with, it doesn't do what you said "_`count number of words with specific length`_", it counts the number of lines having 2 ***characters*** length only not _words_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables won't get expanded in single quotes (`'`).

Normally, you could simply use double quotes (`"`), but for `awk`, this is not a good solution because it will lead to problems with little more complicated `awk` code.

Better assign an `awk` variable with `-v`:

```bsh
awk -v var="$var" 'length == var' mydict.txt | wc -l
```

However, there is no need for `wc -l`, `awk` can do this for you:

```bsh
awk -v var="$var" 'length == var{n++} END{print n}' mydict.txt
```

---

You could also use `grep -c`:

```bsh
grep -c "^.\{$var\}\$" mydict.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers it helped a lot.